# How to redirect all internet traffic to SSH tunnel?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn

First, I'm not a computer expert, I know a bit about networking and its stuff. I'm just an average computer user. So here's the question, I set up an ssh tunnel on my Linux machine with the following command:

```
 ssh -o "ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 127.0.0.1 3339 SERVERIP 443"
 MYUSERNAME@SEVERIP -vND 1080
```

How can I redirect all my internet traffic through that ssh tunnel? so that when I'm browsing google / facebook or any other sites my IP will be detected as `SEVERIP` instead of my real IP address ? It's different from connecting with openvpn where you can just connect to your openvpn account and you're good to go, with ssh tunnel, I have to set all my apps to `socks 127.0.0.1:1080` which I'd like to avoid doing that.

Comment: Well, VPN gives you a separate IP address in the VPN.  That then becomes the 'default route' for traffic (see `ip route` for a full list of IP interfaces, and look for a line like this: `default via 192.168.250.5 dev tun0  proto static`).  An SSH tunnel isn't a 'route' per se, as it's not 'configured' to work as a VPN route.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create `.desktop` files.  You can copy the `google-chrome-stable` to your desktop by typing in from a terminal window:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop /home/username/Desktop
```

Open the `google-chrome.desktop` file with your favorite editor, and change the following line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

to:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

you might also want to change this line close to the beginning of the `.desktop` file from:

```
Name=Google Chrome
```

to

```
Name=Google Chrome (Tunnel)
```

save the file and exit.  Then make the file executable so it can be run:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/username/Desktop/google-chrome.desktop
```

any time you want it to connect through your tunnel you just launch that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traffic from all applications through the SOCKS proxy server `tsocks` would do the trick.

> tsocks is a library to allow transparent SOCKS proxying. It wraps the
>   normal connect() function. When a connection is attempted, it consults
>   the configuration file (which is defined at configure time but
>   defaults to /etc/tsocks.conf) and determines if the IP address
>   specified is local. If it is not, the library redirects the connection
>   to a SOCKS server specified in the configuration file. It then
>   negotiates that connection with the SOCKS server and passes the
>   connection back to the calling program.
>
> Dns Issues
>
> tsocks will normally not be able to send DNS queries through a SOCKS
>   server since SOCKS V4 works on TCP and DNS normally uses UDP. Version
>   1.5 and up do however provide a method to force DNS lookups to use TCP, which then makes them proxyable. This option can only enabled at
>   compile time, please consult the INSTALL file for more information.

If you just want to tunnel browser traffic you should be able to configure a SOCKS proxy in the browser settings.